# Как найти пропущенный ключ в массиве с конца?

Tags: php

Ниже короткий пример массива, в реальности он может достигать милионы значений, желательно находить с максимальной скоростью.

Пропущеных может быть много, нужно только один с конца, из примера ниже пропущеный это 127.

```
$array = [
  121 => 'test',
  123 => 'test',
  124 => 'test',
  125 => 'test',
  126 => 'test',
  128 => 'test',
  129 => 'test',
];
arsort($array);
$result = false;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($array[$key--])) {
        $result = $key;
    }
}
var_dump($result); // выводит false
```

Comment: "милионы значений" .....чую не то вы делаете.... нельзя в память столько загружать......если это из БД - то делается это на стороне БД, а если ещё откуда-то - то как минимум загруать надо порциями....это так, к слову.......а найти просто.....цикл... так что не ясно, что такого сложного сделать цикл

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, понимаю, работаю с тем что есть, обрабатываю файл csv, там поле которое за ключи отвечает все значения рандомно находятся, приходится файл полностью в массив грузить для обработки

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А php массив - это же не настоящий массив, а словарь, и подряд элементы не располагаются, и по индексу нельзя обратиться, да? А то бы бинарный поиск можно было бы применить.

Comment: @MBo как из комментария видно - автор говорит, что значения рандомно... поэтому надо будет ещё и сортировать тогда....а сортировать миллионы значений и потом бинарник - наверное дороже, чем сразу один проход по массиву

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, вы правы. Я посмотрел на упорядоченный пример.

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что получилось:)

```
$array = [
  121 => 'test',
  123 => 'test',
  124 => 'test',
  125 => 'test',
  126 => 'test',
  128 => 'test',
  129 => 'test',
];

$cur = NULL;
$arr = array_keys($array); // получаем ключи
rsort($arr); // sort по убыванию

foreach( $arr as $val )
{
   if( is_null($cur) )
   {
     $cur = $val;
     continue;
   }
   if( $val == $cur ) { continue; } // одинаковые ключи
   if( $val+1 != $cur )
   {
     $val = $val + 1;
     print("Found number: $val\n");
     break;
   }
   $cur = $val;
}
```